# How to change argv[0] from outside?

Tags: c, format-string

I have a C code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void x(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf(argv[0]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* secret = "SECRET";

  if (argc < 2)
    x(argc, argv);
}
```

I now want to do a format string attack to print the secret to the shell. However, I don't know how get the string that I want to argv[0] and how I would access data from another scope (because from x it's not possible to directly address the pointer secret.

How would I do that?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: `printf(argv[0]);` is very wrong.....

Comment: You could name your program `%s` or whatever format string you would like to have in `argv[0]`. It may be prepended by a path though. Actually you can just create a symbolic link, like `ln -s /usr/bin/ls '%s'`. `%s` is used as `argv[0]` in cygwin.

Comment: Why would you even mess around with the command line? Wouldn't it be easier just to read the executable in a hex editor? No programming is needed.

Comment: @Lundin The example is perhaps simplified, and the string may not be present in clear text (or is from somewhere else entirely). And/or it is a proof of concept.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider If the string is not present in clear text, then this method won't work.

Comment: @Lundin `char *pwd = readSecretFromUsbStick();`?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Then it wouldn't be a string literal and not allocated in `.text` but on the stack... or heap... or whatever that function is supposed to do.

Comment: @Lundin Which is why you cannot see it in the executable, but reach it with a malicious `printf` from the stack, where main()'s arguments reside as well. Where the string is is irrelevant; its address (pwd/secret) is on the stack

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider There is nothing in the original program that causes `"SECRET"` to get stored on the stack. You can't assume that the pointer `secret` gets allocated on the stack. It could be placed in an index register or more likely, optimized away entirely.

Comment: @Lundin after `char* secret = ...`, secret, which is on the stack, contains an address; passing that as argument to printf prints whatever it points to -- stack heap, .text.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider What I meant was "There is nothing in the original program that causes `secret` to get stored on the stack.

Answer (score 15):

In unix, programs are started with `execve` (or one of its wrappers, such as `execlp`). All `exec*` functions let you pass arbitrary strings for `argv`, including `argv[0]`.

If you're doing this interactively from a shell, have a look at the `exec` builtin:

```
( exec -a '%x...' ./prog )
```

The parens create a subshell, `exec` loads and runs `./prog` into the subshell process, and the argument to `-a` is used as `argv[0]`.

As for how you can access variables, look at the generated assembler code. If `secret` is stored on the stack and `printf` pulls arguments from the stack, it may be possible to get the results you want just by specifying enough `%x` directives (followed by `%s`).

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly the answer I needed. I guess. Still have to try it out, but it sounds good to me.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it out and it worked perfectly smoothly.

Comment: `exec -a` is a bash-only (not /bin/sh) buitlin

Answer (score 2):

`argv[0]` contains the program name, which is usually the string you invoke the program with. For a program executed with `./a.out`, `argv[0]` would point to `./a.out`.

Your format string attack would need to modify `argv[0]`. That means you need to rename the executable to a format string that fits your needs.

I changed your program to read from `argv[1]` and removed the `argc < 2` restriction. I used `%s` and prepended `%d` until `"SECRET"` was printed. Why `%d`? I figured the stack is aligned to a multiple of `int` (which `%d` prints) because `sizeof(int)` is usually the natural word size.

In the end, I came up with `%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%s`. This prints some values from the stack (if there was some kind of "skipping" formatter to avoid actually printing those values, I'd use it), pops those, and prints `"SECRET"` in the end.

Note that this is undefined behavior and completely dependent on your machine, though.

Comment: If you can change the source code, it is much easier to change it to `int main (void) {puts("SECRET");}`  ...

Comment: @Lundin He renames *the executable.*

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider "I changed your program to read from argv[1] and removed the argc < 2 restriction"

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I took that as making the hack/output easier, not as a precondition. Maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: I changed the source code to make testing easier. Eventually, I reverted back to the OP's code, renamed the executable to the format string that turned out to work, and ran the original code.